# D2: setting array dimensions at runtime

Tags: d

How do you set the dimension of an array when you don't yet know it at compile time?

For instance: byte[][] a = new byte[size][size]; The compiler does not allow it.
How am I supposed to initialize the grid? Manually?

```
byte[] a1;
for (int i; i < size; i++) {
     a1 ~= 0;
} 
byte[][] a2; 
for (int i; i < size; i++) {
     a2 ~= a1;
}
```

Please tell me there is a simpler way.

Edit: this also works, but it is still hopelessly primitive, and slow

```
byte[][] a3; 
a3.length = size;
for (int i; i < size; i++) {
     a3[i].length = size;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't going into depths, here is an example of initializing multidimensional dynamic array in D:

```
auto a = new int[][](4, 4);
```

**Edit:** here goes more complete example (showing that you can initialize array during runtime to avoid confusion):

```
int x = 3, y = 4, z = 5;
auto a = new byte[][][](x, y, z);

Stdout(a[0][0].length).newline; // prints 5
a[0][0].length = 10;
Stdout(a[0][0].length).newline; // prints 10
```

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Of course it should read auto a = new int[][](size, size); But it works. Thanks. I saw this notation before but I can't remember where.

Comment: It should be noted that this still generates a ragged array so resizing it is tricky.